# Passing Multi-value in the input Parameter of the Procedure using Type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How I can pass Multi value in parameter of procedure, using type ?

I want my input parameter of procedure takes multi value, `' 1,2,3,4,5...'` 
and convert it to a table that will contain a column for the entered value and a column for the Row Number ! Using Type or Function.

well first i created object type that contain two attribute( value , Row Number) , and then i created Table of that's type object .
i want like split function but using type , i tried a lot of stuff , but i want at least the  steps .

Comment: What have you tried? Are you aware of collections and records? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm

Comment: if multiple values are obtained from some other table, then use `cursor` or use `for loop`. First of all put some statements or program what you have tried.

Comment: no i enter the values in the procedure

Comment: its better to use `for loop` if you have assigned the values already in procedure.

Comment: i want to convert it to table so i can join it with other tables

Comment: if only one column, and all the values to be inserted into one column, then better create a new table with one column. Making codes look longer and complex does not require when we can finish the job in few simple steps..

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple table...

```
create table table1 (column1 number);
```

Create a procedure...

```
create or replace procedure proc_one
(v_input IN table1.column1%type)
IS
v_local number;
begin
      insert into table1 values (v_input);
end;
```

and run an anonymous block with loop and execute procedure every time until all rows in the column are looped through.

```
declare
var_local number;
begin
      --select count(column1) into v_local from table1;
      --or
      --var_local := 1;
      --or
      for i in (select column1 from table) loop
      proc_one(i.column1);
      end loop;
exception
      when others then
           dbms_output.put_line('Calling procedure has been failed.');
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

hi If you have only integer values in input parameter then you can user xmltable. v_list is your input values in row; it will convert row into column(collection of elements) and collect into my_list a collection variable.

```
select to_number(column_value)
  bulk collect into my_list
  from xmltable(vList);
```